# Template argument deduction goes wrong

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, arguments

What I'm trying to accomplish here is the calculation of the determinant of some NxN matrix. Determinant is defined like so:

`det M = MikCik(M)`, where *i* loops from 1 through N and *k* is an arbitrarily chosen constant such that 1 <= k <= N

"C" is the cofactor that is defined as follows:

`Cij(M) = (-1)i + j det M{i, j}`, where **M**<sup>{i, j}</sup> denotes the (N-1)x(N-1) matrix whose entries consist of the original entries of **M** after deleting the *i*-th row and *j*-th column

Now, here is my code:

```
template <typename T, const int N>
T determinant(const TMatrixNxM<T, N, N> &par_value)
{
    T result = T(0);

    switch (N)
    {
    case 1:
        //Hardcoded for 1x1 matrix:
        result = par_value[0][0];
        break;
    case 2:
        //Hardcoded for 2x2 matrix:
        result = par_value[0][0] * par_value[1][1] - par_value[0][1] * par_value[1][0];
        break;
    case 3:
        //Hardcoded for 3x3 matrix:
        result = par_value[0][0] * (par_value[1][1] * par_value[2][2] - par_value[1][2] * par_value[2][1]) - par_value[0][1] * (par_value[1][0] * par_value[2][2] - par_value[1][2] * par_value[2][0]) + par_value[0][2] * (par_value[1][0] * par_value[2][1] - par_value[1][1] * par_value[2][0]);
        break;
    default:
        //i loops through 0 to N-1, k is arbitrarily chosen to be 0
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            result += par_value[i][0] * cofactor(par_value, i, 0);
        }
        break;
    }

    return result;
}

template <typename T, const int N>
T cofactor(const TMatrixNxM<T, N, N> &par_value, int par_i, int par_j)
{
    T result = T(0);

    //Construct the new matrix, without the i-th row j-th column
    TMatrixNxM<T, N - 1, N - 1> newMatrix;

    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        int l = 0;

        if (k == par_i) k++;

        for (int j = 0; j < N - 1; j++)
        {
            if (l == par_j) l++;

            newMatrix[i][j] = par_value[k][l];

            l++;
        }

        k++;
    }

    result = pow(-1, (par_i + 1) + (par_j + 1)) * determinant(newMatrix); //I have to add +1 to i and j since I started from 0

    return result;
}
```

And testing it:

```
TMatrixNxM<float, 3, 3> mat1;
//Set values
float det = determinant(mat1);
```

However, the compiler gives me these errors:
Warning 3   warning C4200: nonstandard extension used : zero-sized array in struct/union
Error   4   error C2118: negative subscript
which refer to the arrays of data that hold the values of matrices

And when I see the rest of the compiler output, I see that it is trying to deduce the arguments with N set to 0, and even -1. What's going on here? Clearly, it shouldn't ever go that far (actually, as I can see, it shouldn't go lower than 3).

Also, if I comment out the recursive call to the determinant function in the cofactor function, it compiles (it calculates the new matrix correctly, too). Or, if I comment out the entire "default" part in the determinant function, it compiles (and it calculates the hardcoded determinants correctly, too).

Thank you for your time

**EDIT 1**

Code requested in comments, showing the declaration of data arrays:

```
template <typename T, const int N, const int M>
class TMatrixNxM
{
public:
    TMatrixNxM(T = T(0));
    //Other things
protected:
    TVectorND<T, M> data[N];
};
```

and

```
template <typename T, const int N>
class TVectorND
{
public:
    TVectorND(T = T(0));
    //Other things
protected:
    T data[N];
};
```

Comment: You will need to show the code that corresponds to those errors. The error should indicate where they came from (probably the template definition for `TMatrixNxM`)

Comment: OT, but `result = pow(-1,` is not a great idea because `pow` is a floating-point function; consider just doing `-1` if odd and `+1` if even

Comment: You should specialize your method for some `N` because even if the branch is not taken, the function should be generated.

Comment: @Matt McNabb: See the update, does that cut it? And also, thanks for advice.

Comment: @Jarod42: You mean I should make completely new functions or? But wouldn't that do the same thing then, since I have to branch the calls still. Or did I not understand?

Comment: See T.C.'s answer, it is mostly what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the code's not actually reached, the compiler needs to be able to be able to compile the whole body of `determinant`. Thus, even for `N = 3`, you still need to be able to call `cofactor` with `N = 3`, which in turn calls `determinant` with `N = 2`. In turn that requires being able to call `cofactor` with `N = 2` and `determinant` with `N = 1`, and so on, until you get to `N = -1` and a compile error.

Instead of `switch`ing on `N` in `determinant`, use overloading templates:

```
template <typename T>
T determinant(const TMatrixNxM<T, 1, 1> &par_value)
{
    T result = T(0);
    result = par_value[0][0];    
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
T determinant(const TMatrixNxM<T, 2, 2> &par_value)
{
    T result = T(0);
    result = par_value[0][0] * par_value[1][1] - par_value[0][1] * par_value[1][0];
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
T determinant(const TMatrixNxM<T, 3, 3> &par_value)
{
    T result = T(0);
    result = par_value[0][0] * (par_value[1][1] * par_value[2][2] - par_value[1][2] * par_value[2][1]) - par_value[0][1] * (par_value[1][0] * par_value[2][2] - par_value[1][2] * par_value[2][0]) + par_value[0][2] * (par_value[1][0] * par_value[2][1] - par_value[1][1] * par_value[2][0]);
    return result;
}

template <typename T, const int N>
T determinant(const TMatrixNxM<T, N, N> &par_value)
{
    static_assert(N >= 4, "Default determinant called for N<4");
    T result = T(0);

    //i loops through 0 to N-1, k is arbitrarily chosen to be 0
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        result += par_value[i][0] * cofactor(par_value, i, 0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05ccfa9b22f4d9b2).

Comment: Why `2` and `3` versions?

Comment: @Yakk Because they were in the OP?